# Media file is not uploaded via Azure Media Services

Tags: .net, azure, windows-media-services

I'm trying to upload a mp4 file into azure media services. Just upload, no encoding/encrypting.
My code is as follows

```
CloudMediaContext context = new CloudMediaContext("<id>", "<secret>");
var asset = context.Assets.Create("MyFile", AssetCreationOptions.None);
var file = asset.AssetFiles.Create("MyFile.mp4");
file.Upload(@"e:\MyFile.mp4");
```

Using Fiddler I can see that the file is uploaded. But when I go into Azure management Console I can see an asset with the name "MyFile", but it's size is 0!
Could you please advise?

Comment: **you can refer this link**

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465040/cant-upload-to-azure-media-services-file-not-found/16767326#16767326

Comment: **you can refer this link**
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465040/cant-upload-to-azure-media-services-file-not-found/16767326#16767326

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a bug in the SDK that causes the content size to say 0. Apparently it is fixed in the next release of the SDK.

See the comment in the following post for more info :
[Thread on latest Azure Media SDK](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/da-dk/mediaservices/thread/7417b76a-d670-4b2c-8024-0e1c2ce4b803)

Comment: I don't think that's the reason. The management console shows size as 0 and it's really zero, because the file has no associated BLOB.

Comment: For me it works fine. If you go to your blob storage you should see the file was uploaded. Even though is says 0b in Media Services it still encodes just fine for me.