# Can't upload to Azure Media Services - File Not Found

Tags: azure-media-services

When I run the website locally, the video will upload to azure and I get a publish url. No problem. However, when I publish the website and then try to upload from there, I get this error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>       --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
c:\V1.mp4 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: c:\V1.mp4

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 



[FileNotFoundException: c:\V1.mp4]
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AssetFileData.UploadAsync(String path, BlobTransferClient blobTransferClient, ILocator locator, CancellationToken token) +499
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<UploadAsync>b__14(Task`1 t) +347
   System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromResultTask`1.InnerInvoke() +80
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute() +49

[AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) +3548265
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +10487717
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait() +10
   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AssetFileData.Upload(String path) +90
   UploadTest.Upload.UploadVideoButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +101
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9553594
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724`enter code here`
```

Upload.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Upload.aspx.cs" Inherits="UploadTest.Upload" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="UploadVideoButton" runat="server" Text="Upload The Video" OnClick="UploadVideoButton_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

Upload.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client;

namespace UploadTest
{
    public partial class Upload : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void UploadVideoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CloudMediaContext context = new CloudMediaContext("<accountname>", "<accountkey>");
            var asset = context.Assets.Create("V1.mp4", AssetCreationOptions.None);
            var file = asset.AssetFiles.Create("V1.mp4");
            file.Upload(@"c:\V1.mp4");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it's not just that the file V1.mp4 doesn't exist on the server's C:\ drive? That's what the FileNotFound exception would suggest...

Answer (score -1):

**I think you should use this to upload file by uploading the stream**

```
public void UploadFileToAzure(Stream stream, string fileName, string contentType, 
    EContextType contextType) {
    if (stream == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("stream");

    if (fileName == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("fileName");

    CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = null;

    switch (contextType)
    {
        case EContextType.CloudStorage:
            blobContainer = AzureBlobUtil.InitializeBlob(Settings.AzureBlobStorageFileStorage, Settings.GetAzureDataConnectionString);
            break;
        default:
            blobContainer = AzureBlobUtil.InitializeBlob(Settings.AzureBlobStorageDocument, Settings.GetAzureDataConnectionString);
            break;
    }

    var blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
    blob.UploadFromStream(stream);

    blob.Metadata["FileName"] = fileName;
    blob.Metadata["IsArchived"] = false.ToString();
    blob.SetMetadata();
    // Set the properties
    blob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;

    blob.SetProperties();
}
```